# "audio/mpeg" stream api fails for some files plays some files?

Tags: java, android, rest, audio, mpeg-4

We are recording some audios on Android phones which are having the following format as per vlc information:

```
Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
Language: English
Type: Audio
Channels: Stereo
Sample rate: 32000 Hz
Bits per sample: 32
```

The above files were not playing on the safari browser with mime type `audio/mpeg`, But as soon as we changed the mime to `audio/mp4` it started playing on safari browser.
For Android we are using API to stream this file using api resource as follows :

```
@GET
    @UnitOfWork
    @Produces("audio/mpeg")
    @Path("/getaudiofile/{fileId}")
    public Response getPart(@Auth AuthUser authUser, @PathParam("fileId") Long fileId) {

 File audioFile = new File(filesTableDAO.getFilePathById(fileId));

if(audioFile.exists()) {
return Response.ok().entity(audioFile).build();
} else {
// ... Return 404 here
}

}
```

But with above API some files getting played & some are not, Similar to Safari case earlier. But safari problem went away ASAP we changed mime to `"audio/mp4"` or `"video/mp4"` both the mime type work.

But for the API `/getaudiofile/{fileId}` none of the following mime types worked with the `javax.ws.rs @Produces` annotaion :

```
    audio/mp4
    video/mp4
    audio/mpeg
    audio/m4a
    audio/mpeg-4
audio/mp4a
```

But with `audio/mpeg` some of the files play but some don't.

What may be the right mime type or can file set the codec or mime info itself while returning from API ?

Or Is there any way to make [Android Media Player](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) MIME type aware? Like  [html tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all).

We have streamed file content of mime "audio/mpeg" the media player plays smaller sized files easily. But bigger streamed content fails to play e.g. 10 - 20 MB.

Problem with stream URL the player do not get any mime extension e.g. mp3, or mp4. Hence we want the media player to know in advance what type of the content is being streamed.

Does the MediaPlayer API support setting mime type to player instance prior to playing?

***Update***

1] This is happening for files with big sizes small files play very well, An recording of few seconds ( 1-50 secs ) play without a problem, An recording file with playback length of more than minute fails to play.

2] When played from authenticated URL playback fails if the same file is on local file system plays flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming

Above project by [Arul Dhesiaseelan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794988/arul-dhesiaseelan) solved my issue, The way I wrote get file Resource was not efficient, In above GitHub project take look into [MediaResource.java](https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming/blob/master/src/main/java/com/aruld/jersey/streaming/MediaResource.java).

This is the proper way of streaming media files, Adjust mime-types as per your file.

I set headers to media player as follows:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_AUTH_TOKEN>");
            headers.put("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            headers.put("Status", "206");
            headers.put("Cache-control", "no-cache");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), uri, headers);
```

Now I am able to stream media with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, perhaps you might try

> **openTypedAssetFile**
>
> public *AssetFileDescriptor*  openTypedAssetFile (Uri uri, 
>                   String mimeTypeFilter, 
>                   Bundle opts)
>
> Called by a client to open a read-only stream containing data of a particular MIME type. This is like
>   openAssetFile(Uri, String), except the file can only be read-only and
>   the content provider may perform data conversions to generate data of
>   the desired type.

Documentation for `openTypedAssetFile` is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#openTypedAssetFile(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Also look at the API for `openWTypedAssetFileDescriptor` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Comment: Feied there is no way I can add authentication headers while using above method